# jquery onkey left right slide not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the lef and right keys to horizontally go through a paginated listing with php.After pressing the right key, Jquery seems to be stuck on a single number which is number 2. I was wondering what am i doing wrong below:   Thank you very much.

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
                function loading_show(){
                    $('#loading').html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
                }
                function loading_hide(){
                    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
                }                
                function loadData(page){
                    loading_show();
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "load_data.php",
                        data: "page="+page, 
                        success: function(msg)
                        {
                            $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                            {
                                loading_hide();
                                $("#container").html(msg);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
                $('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                    var page = $(this).attr('p');
                    loadData(page);

                });           
                $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                    var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                    var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                    if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                        loadData(page);
                    }else{
                        alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                        $('.goto').val("").focus();
                        return false;
                    }

                });

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        //do while( ){

        var page = $('#container .pagination li.active').attr('p');
        var add= 1
        var key = parseInt(page) + parseInt(add);
        //document.write(key);
                    loadData(key);
                    var page = key
        //}

       return false;
    }
});
            });
```

Comment: When you go to next remove active class from all li and add active class to next li also remove active class from all li and if you go to previous then add active class to previous one.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('keyup', function() {
        var KEY_LEFT = 37;
        var KEY_RIGHT = 39;

        var currentPage = $('#container .pagination li.active');

        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case KEY_LEFT:
                var page = currentPage.removeClass('active')
                                        .prev()
                                        .addClass('active')
                                        .attr('data-page');

                loadData(page);
                break;

            case KEY_RIGHT:
                var page = currentPage.removeClass('active')
                                        .next()
                                        .addClass('active')
                                        .attr('data-page');

                loadData(page);
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li data-page="3">3</li>
    <li data-page="4">4</li>
    <li class="active" data-page="5">5</li>
    <li data-page="6">6</li>
    <li data-page="7">7</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you're missing semi-colons here: `var add= 1` and here: `var page = key`. Second, without your full HTML code, no one here can definitely identify the precise problem. This problem involves an AJAX response and we don't have an example response to review in your question.

Regardless, if you're getting stuck on the second page, then the `p` attribute of your `li.active` element is not incrementing--it is set to 1 with every page load. The server-side process responsible for serving up the HTML is not returning the HTML you're expecting. Try using `console.log` or an alert to verify the content of the HTML:

Inside your `.ajaxComplete` method:

```
alert(msg);
```

You should find that the `p` attribute is always set to 1.